# Issue with image on button duplicating

Tags: image, winforms, user-interface

We recently moved a program from windows server 2012 R2 to windows server 2022 and for some reason buttons that have an image with multiple images are displaying more than just the one image.  It should look like the image on the right. The images with green are what the buttons are using.  Has anyone seen this before?

[image: Example of issue]

Comment: The images are clearly distorted. Since these Buttons are probably owner-drawn, you have to consider the DpiAwareness of the application. You didn't say what .NET version you're targeting or whether the application is DpiAware and, in this case, what mode is set. If it's not DpiAware, you have to introduce `PerMonitorV2` DpiAwaress, and a few design changes

Comment: Thank you Jimi.  The dpi aware is set to no and I think it uses v4 .net this is a third party program.  I will ask them to see if any of your ideas are something we can try.   This is what I see in the config <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>

Comment: The *runtime version* is always 4.0. It's the `sku` that comes after what matters. If it's .NET Framework and the version is less that 4.7.1, changing the DpiAwareness mode (in `app.config`) may not be enough and, most probably, redesign is needed. Since this is not an application you have developed, this question is not about coding or refactoring to fix a problem. You can probably try to tinker with the compatibility settings of the executable. Maybe activating extended GDI+ support could fix the visual issue. But it's not a StackOverflow question anymore

Comment: Ok thank you ill close it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a third party app that I or the community can help with I am closing this out with Jim's answer.

The runtime version is always 4.0. It's the sku that comes after what matters. If it's .NET Framework and the version is less that 4.7.1, changing the DpiAwareness mode (in app.config) may not be enough and, most probably, redesign is needed. Since this is not an application you have developed, this question is not about coding or refactoring to fix a problem. You can probably try to tinker with the compatibility settings of the executable. Maybe activating extended GDI+ support could fix the visual issue. But it's not a StackOverflow question anymore